# jQuery variables inner selectors are not supported by IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

The code below adds a link to an upload field. For each new click it shows a new upload field to the form up to a total 5. There are no errors in Chrome etc.

I would like to know what is wrong with the line below as it seems the script works well on other browsers but on IE8 it throws an error: `Object doesn't support this action`. Can you suggest alternative code?

```
<div id="edit-submitted-file1-ajax-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    //upload field here
</div>
<a id="addmore" href="#">[+] Add more</a>

<div id="edit-submitted-file2-ajax-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    //upload field here
</div>

<div id="edit-submitted-file3-ajax-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    //upload field here
</div>
```

etc

```
first = $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').first();
        first.after('<a id="addmore" href=#>[+] Add more</a>');
        $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            first.show();
        });

var c = 0;
$('#addmore').bind('click', function(e) {
    //HERE BELOW IS THE LINE WITH ERROR
    item = $('#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper');
    item.show();
    ++c;
    if (c == 5) {
        $('#addmore').hide();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What object, what action, and what does your HTML Look like? Have you actually looked at a debugger when this runs?

Comment: What is c here? Is item a valid jquery element? If not, you will get the object doesnt support error because item will end up being null.

Comment: What is the variable `c`, some loop counter?

Comment: The variables counts up to 5 new dom elements to be added

Comment: That still does not answer the question if $('#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper'); is a valid element? Can you check that in your code?

Comment: On the first click it tries to `show()` the element `edit-submitted-file0-ajax-wrapper` which does not exist. Can you add the code to your example where you are actually appending the inputs.

Comment: [div#edit-submitted-file0-ajax-wrapper]
[div#edit-submitted-file1-ajax-wrapper]
[div#edit-submitted-file2-ajax-wrapper]  this is I got after each click in Chrome console: console.log(item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
item = $('#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper');
```

to this

```
var item = $('#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fJ3EG/2/

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no dice. :(

Comment: @FarcasO. Strange, I got the same result. It works fine with var. Ensure that your code is not cached.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably used the word 'item' somewhere in your html before. Declare your variable as `var item` and the problem should be solved.

See this earlier post on Stackoverflow:

> My guess is that you have something on your page that has either the name or id "item",
>   and so that's becoming a property of window because IE does that (...)

[ie, javascript and 'item' as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435677/ie-javascript-and-item-as-a-variable-name)